# Getting user input from Win32 C++. WPARAM casted as int?

Tags: c++, winapi, input, keyboard

I'm working on a pre-existing codebase and I'm looking to have the user type any 1-2 digits followed by the enter key at any time during the code being run and pass that number to a function.  Currently, user input is handled like so:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    int wmId, wmEvent;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        Engine::GetInstance()->GetInput()->GetKeyboard()->SetKeyPressed(static_cast<int>(wParam));
        break;
        //snip
```

Now, I'm not sure of a few things,

- a) Why would the keypressed be passed as an integer rather than a character?
- b) What would be the result of "F1" being sent in this case aaand
- c) How can I use this to read in a 1-2 digit number and pass that only when enter is pressed?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this using WM_KEYDOWN? For cooked keyboard input, WM_CHAR would be a better choice--it'll handle numeric keypads and other input weirdness.

Answer (score 4):

a) The value sent here is a virtual-key code, not necessarily a character.

b) See list of virtual key codes [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646280%28VS.85%29.aspx) (given in a comment). F1 would be represented by VK_F1 (0x70).

c) When a digit is pressed, add it to a string containing the last digit presses. When any other key is pressed, clear the string. When enter  is pressed, act based on the string value.

**Edit**: This would be a bit complicated in `WM_KEYDOWN` since you would need to handle both the normal digit keys and the numpad keys. It will be easier to handle the `WM_CHAR` message instead, which receives the character code in wParam.

Comment: So am I going to need to do a switch for each virtual key representing 0-9?  It seems like it should be able to just take in direct input, no?

Comment: No need for a switch, you can use something like: 

`if (key>='0' && key<='9') digitsPressed += (char)key;` 

For digits, the virtual key codes are the same as ASCII codes

Comment: Actually, my last comment won't handle the numpad keys properly - see my edited answer.